# Objeto como propiedad de objeto

Tags: c#, clase

estoy recogiendo los pedidos de una tienda online, yo los recojo en un objeto pedidos.

```
namespace pedidos
{
    public class Corder
    {
        public class Cabecera
        {
            private Detalle _linies;
            public List<Detalle> Linies { get; set; }
            public Guid idDocumento { get; set; }
            public int CodigoEmpresa { get; set; }
        public int NumeroDocumento { get; set; }
        };
        public class Detalle
        {
             public int NumeroDocumento { get; set; }
             public string CodigoArticulo { get; set; }
             public string DescripcionArticulo { get; set; }
             public decimal? Unidades { get; set; }
             public decimal? Precio { get; set; }
             public int? idLinia { get; set; }

        }
    }
}
```

Faltan muchas propiedades, por no tener que pegar demasiado código.
EL caso es que la cabecera tiene una propiedad que es una lista de objetos detalle, un pedido tiene varias líneas.
Seguro que hay millones de maneras mejores de hacerlo, pero es lo que tiene ser un novato.
Para llenar estos objetos, lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
private void btTraspassar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CItaules taules = new CItaules();
            Corder.Cabecera cap;
            var filtre = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "status", "completed" } };
            List<Order> Lorders = Task.Run(() => rec.Order.GetAll(filtre)).Result;
            List<Corder.Cabecera> cabeceras = new List<Corder.Cabecera>();
            foreach (Order order in Lorders)
            {
                Guid lOguid = Funcions.creaGUID(order.id.ToString());
                cap = new Corder.Cabecera();     
                cap.idDocumento = Funcions.creaGUID(order.id.ToString());
                cap.CodigoCliente = order.customer_id.ToString();
                cap.CodigoEmpresa = int.Parse(GlobalVar.Empresa);
                cap.FechaDocumento = order.date_completed;
                cap.NumeroDocumento = int.Parse(order.number);
                foreach (WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v2.OrderLineItem linia in order.line_items)
                {
                cap.Linies.Add(new Corder.Detalle()
                {
                    idLinia = linia.id,
                    NumeroDocumento = linia.number
                    CodigoArticulo = linia.product_id.ToString(),
                    DescripcionArticulo = linia.name,
                    Precio = linia.price,
                    Unidades = linia.quantity
                });
                }
                cabeceras.Add(cap);
            }
        }
```

Pero cuando intenta crear las líneas me arroja una excepción en el `cap.Linies.Add` :

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida
>   como instancia de un objeto.'
>   ¿Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal?
>   Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tienes que inicializar la propiedad. Añade despues de `cap = new Corder.Cabecera(); ` algo como `cap.Linies = new List<Detalle>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que nunca inicializas la lista `Linies`, por lo que es `null` y no puedes llamar al método `Add`.

Deberías inicializarla o bien cuando estás creando el objeto `Cabecera`...

```
cap = new Corder.Cabecera();
cap.Linies = new List<Corder.Detalle>();
// Aquí ya podrías llamar a cap.Linies.Add(...)
```

... o puedes inicializarla por defecto en la propia clase.

```
public class Cabecera
{
    private Detalle _linies;
    public List<Detalle> Linies { get; set; } = new List<Detalle>();
    // ...
}
```

Cada vez que se cree un objeto `new Corder.Cabecera()` tambié se creara la `List<Corder.Detalle>` por defecto.

Espero que sirva.